# Highcharts Gantt / X labels disappear randomly

Tags: highcharts

Sorry to bother "again", we have a couple of important questions, we noticed that some of the X labels disappear randomly, my understanding is that sometimes, when we don't have space, labels should hide but this behavior is happening even if there's space, we have version 10.3.1 of Gantt, please check the following for better understanding:
[image]

**and also...**

[image]

Now we would like to ask if there's a solution for this? or an update? also would like to ask something related... as you can see in the images, we have divided the X into 3 lines, years, quarters and months, **is there a way to have the months 3 letters as shown when there's enough space and show only the month initial when the space is reduced?**

Thank you for any help you may bring!

Comment: Hi @Guillermo Perez, Could you reproduce the problem? You can use this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nau4kydg/ as a base to start.

Answer (score 1):

You may try setting the `padding` to 0 or to set `allowOverlap=true`

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.allowOverlap

Comment: I tried adding the options but nothing happens, same BAD behavior... any other ideas?